# Outer join with blank spaces to accomodate both sides

Tags: join

I am trying to join two tables both relating to cities. One table has the columns City and Writer, the other has City and Park. I want to end up with a table that has the columns Writer City Park. If for a particular city, there are 9 writers and 5 parks, then there will be 9 lines for that city, but 4 blank spaces in the parks column (and vice versa).

Comment: [Read up on joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Comment: If there 9 writers and 5 parks in a city, shouldn't the result be 45 rows? (each writer associated with each park?)

Comment: Might be good to show your own attempt first. This is a very basic SQL join question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table CityWriter (City varchar(20), Writer varchar(20))

Insert into CityWriter values
('New York', 'Dylan'),
('Chicago', 'Pierce'),
('Los Angeles', null),
('Portland', 'Steinbeck')


Create Table CityPark   (City varchar(20), Park varchar(20))

Insert into CityPark values
('New York', 'Park1'),
('Chicago', 'Park2'),
('Los Angeles', 'Park3'),
('Portland', 'Park4'),
('Houston', null),
('Denver', 'Axl Rose'),
('San Fancisco', null)

Select * from CityWriter cw 
         full join CityPark cp
            on cp.City = cw.City
```